# How will added from SD card Specific folder URL path "Universal Image Loader "

Tags: android, image, universal-image-loader, universal

Has i am create sample Gallery using "Universal Image Loader" i will given one by one static image path !! How to added  images path in dynamically using Universal Image Loader concept.

Sample Code Contants.java :

```
   public final class Constants {



public static final String[] IMAGES = new String[] {
        // Heavy images
            "file:///sdcard/DCIM/IMG_20151026_172237570.jpg", // Image from SD card with encoded symbols
            "file:///sdcard/DCIM/IMG_20151026_172241845.jpg", // Image from SD card with encoded symbols
            "file:///sdcard/DCIM/IMG_20151026_172251959.jpg", // Image from SD card with encoded symbols
            "file:///sdcard/DCIM/IMG_20151026_172255739.jpg", // Image from SD card with encoded symbols
            "file:///sdcard/DCIM/IMG_20151026_172258063.jpg", // Image from SD card with encoded symbols
        "file:///sdcard/DCIM/IMG_20151026_172258063.jpg", // Image from SD card with encoded symbols
        "file:///sdcard/DCIM/IMG_20151026_172258063.jpg", // Image from SD card with encoded symbols




};

private Constants() {
}

public static class Config {
    public static final boolean DEVELOPER_MODE = false;
}

public static class Extra {
    public static final String FRAGMENT_INDEX = "com.nostra13.example.universalimageloader.FRAGMENT_INDEX";
    public static final String IMAGE_POSITION = "com.nostra13.example.universalimageloader.IMAGE_POSITION";
}
}
```

This is the code .... How to given on dynamically different in run time access its , given me solutions friends!!

Answer (score 0):

--Here is the **solutions** you can see

```
string imgPath = "/file:///sdcard/DCIM/IMG_20151026_172237570.jpg";

String decodedImgUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(imgPath)).toString();
ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(decodedImgUri, imageView);
```